# Run part of a makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile that consists of different parts. I wonder how I can run only part of the makefile, for instance `%.stats` ?

Makefile:

```
%.int:  %Aligned.out.sam
        htseq-count -s no -i gene -t exon $< ${gff} > $@
         ....
%.mrna: %.int
         cat $< | head -n -5 > $@
         ....

%.stats: %.int
        numm=$$(cat $*Log.final.out | grep "Number of reads" |cut -f
        ....
```

Comment: `make somefile.stats`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a pattern rule without specifying what you want the pattern to match. `make one.stats two.stats` will run `%.stats` twice for with the stem set to `one` and `two`, respectively. Perhaps there is a definition earlier on in the `Makefile` with something like

```
.PHONY: all_stats
all_stats: $(patsubst %.int,%.stats,$(wildcard *.int))
```

or some such, in which case you can obviously say `make all_stats` to run it for each of the input files it depends on.

If not, perhaps you can do something in the shell, like

```sh
make $(printf '%s\n' *.int | sed 's/\.int$/.stats/')
```

If the `%.int` target is also just intermediate, perhaps you can find the original dependency, and map to that. For example, if `%.stats` depends on `%.int` and `%.int` depends on `%.orig`, obviously `%.stats` transitively depends on `%.orig`, so you can map `.orig` to `.stats` using either of the above.

Comment: all:    ${targets_mrna} $(subst .mrna,.stats,${targets_mrna}) .mrna

Comment: That runs something else, but if you can edit the file to do something similar for `.stats`, there you have it.